# shell script to generate new log with date stamp

Tags: linux, shell, unix, logging

Is there a way to extract the last modified date and time from a log file and attach that date and time to the file?

I have a tool that generates appslist.log file every time it is run.
Through my script when I run the tool, the applist.log file is already there and then I may have to associate it with the time and date it was created.

Like:

```
mv applist.log applist_+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.log
```

Like let's say I ran the tool the first time and it generated applist.log:

```
applist.log     Mon 03-29-2013
```

The next time I run the tool on 03-30-2013, I want to move the existing applist.log file with a new name containing the date and time it was created:

```
like applist_03-29-2013.log
```

because the tool would again generate applist.log on 03-30-2013.

Comment: Have you looked at logrotate? http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv applist.log applist_`date -r applist.log +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.log
```

This will move the file to a new file with a date in the name.  The date command allows you to display in any format.  See `man date` for a full description of these character sequences.  Using back ticks will run the command inside first.  The `-r` option on date will get the date of the file in question.

Example:

```
[me@host temp]$ mv applist.log applist_`date -r applist.log +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.log
[me@host temp]$ ls -l
total 196
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me     0 Mar 25 20:55 applist_20130325205532.log
```

I assume your program is a cron and will not run more than once a second.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the creation time of a file depends on the file system you're using.
Not all file systems support retrieving file creation time. Try:

```
stat --format=%w applist.log
```

If you get a single '-', your file system does *not* report the creation time. Otherwise, it prints the time.

If you get the creation time this way, you may use the following to do the move:

```
fileName="applist.log"  
creationTimeEpoch="$(stat --format=%W "${fileName}")"  
creationTime="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S --date="@${creationTimeEpoch}")"  
mv -i "${fileName}" "${fileName%.log}_${creationTime}.log"
```

If not, you may use the modification time of the file:

```
fileName="applist.log"  
modificationTime="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S --reference="${fileName}")"  
mv -i "${fileName}" "${fileName%.log}_${modificationTime}.log"
```